# What does the offset in front of ($sp) actually represent? Where is it offset from initially?

Tags: stack, mips, mars-simulator

What does the offset represent with the stack pointer? Where is it offset from? The initial location of the stack pointer or the most recent location of the stack pointer.  I am trying to step through a program in MARS and trying to trace where the value/register will be placed on the stack and it is not going where I think it should go.

I have been stepping through and things keep getting stored in unexpected locations on the stack.

For example:

```
addi $t1, $zero, -1
sw $t1, ($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, -24
addi $t2, $zero, -2
sw $t2, ($sp)
addi $t2, $zero, -3
sw $t3, 16($sp)
```

What is offset 16 "offset" from? Where the stack started out, or the last location of the pointer?

Comment: Think about it: Does `16($r29)` refer to an offset of 16 from where `$r29` started out, or the last value of `$r29`? (Note also that your code stores an uninitialized `$t3`.)

Comment: I got it! Thanks on the code with on $t3. I just move the offset from the last place the sp was explicitly moved to. If we subtract 20 from the sp (moving the address of the sp from 48 to 28), then 0($sp) is exactly where the sp is now (address 28) and if I tried to store in 4($sp) it is in address 32. And 16($sp) would be address 44 and so on...